# Deploy JEE/JPA Aplication without active Database Connection

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have the following scenario. I have a JEE6 based Enterprise Application that is connected to a single Database via JPA and a DataSource setup in my Application Server (Glassfish) and a pooled Database Connection.

I now want to extend my application with Database Failover Handling. To achieve this I have added a second DataSource, added it as a second persistence-unit, I have a single entry point that switches DataSources, all well so far.

However, with a simulated crash of either database, If I want to deploy my Application, I get errors that my Database is not available, and my application won't deploy. But since this is an expected behaviour, does anybody know any kind of way to deactive this and let it deploy even though my database is MIA, or some other kind of workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: maybe this urls can shed some light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557967/accessing-multiple-database-from-a-java-web-application-using-jpa-eclipselink-ej and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445671/glassfish-silently-ignore-unavailable-data-source-at-application-start-up and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973999/entitymanager-object-is-not-getting-injected-with-glassfish-and-spring and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085944/how-to-handle-database-crashes-glassfish-mysql